# Returning the prime factors of a number

Tags: performance, primes, lisp, common-lisp, factors

I am trying to create a function `prime-factors` that returns the prime factors of a number. To do so, I created `is-prime` function, and `prime-factors-helper` that will do a recursive check of the prime factors.

```
(defun is-prime (n &optional (d (- n 1))) 
  (if (/= n 1) (or (= d 1)
          (and (/= (rem n d) 0)
               (is-prime  n (- d 1)))) ()))

(defun prime-factors-helper (x n)
   (if (is-prime x) 
       (list x) 
       (if (is-prime n) 
            (if (AND (= (mod x n) 0) (<= n (/ x 2)))
                (cons n (prime-factors-helper (/ x n) n))
                (prime-factors-helper x (+ 1 n)))       
            (prime-factors-helper x (+ 1 n)))))

(defun prime-factors (x)
    (prime-factors-helper x 2))
```

I have a problem of optimisation. When I have a big number such as `123456789`, I get this error message "Stack overflow (stack size 261120)". I believe because the correct answer of `(prime-factors 123456789)` is `(3 3 3607 3803)`, my program will take so long to find the next prime factor once it constructs the list with the two first elements `(3 3)`. How can I optimise my code?

```
 CL-USER 53 > (prime-factors 512)
 (2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2)

 CL-USER 54 > (prime-factors 123456789)

 Stack overflow (stack size 261120).
   1 (abort) Return to level 0.
   2 Return to top loop level 0.

 Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
 Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options
```

Comment: please fix indentation (use Emacs if unsure). your code is now unreadable.

Answer (score 6):

There are several problems with your code.

## Style

1. `is-prime` is C/Java style. Lispers use `primep` or `prime-number-p`.
2. [`zerop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_zerop.htm) is clearer than `(= 0 ...)`.
3. Lispers use *indentation*, not paren counting, to read code.  Your
   code is thus virtually unreadable.  Please use Emacs if you are
   unsure how to format lisp properly.

## Stack overflow

`is-prime` is tail-recursive, so if you compile it, it should become a
simple loop and there should be no stack issues.

However, do not rush with it yet.

## Algorithm

### Number of iterations

Let us use [`trace`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_tracec.htm) to see the
problems:

```
> (prime-factors 17)
1. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17)
2. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '15)
3. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '14)
4. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '13)
5. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '12)
6. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '11)
7. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '10)
8. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '9)
9. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '8)
10. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '7)
11. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '6)
12. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '5)
13. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '4)
14. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '3)
15. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '2)
16. Trace: (IS-PRIME '17 '1)
16. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
15. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
14. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
13. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
12. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
11. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
10. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
9. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
8. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
7. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
6. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
5. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
4. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
3. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
2. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
1. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
(17)
```

You do 17 iterations when only `(isqrt 17) = 4` iterations are necessary.

### Recalculations

Now compile `is-prime` to turn recursion into a loop and see:

```
> (prime-factors 12345)
1. Trace: (IS-PRIME '12345)
1. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> NIL
1. Trace: (IS-PRIME '2)
1. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
1. Trace: (IS-PRIME '12345)
1. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> NIL
1. Trace: (IS-PRIME '3)
1. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
1. Trace: (IS-PRIME '4115)
1. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> NIL
1. Trace: (IS-PRIME '3)
1. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
1. Trace: (IS-PRIME '4115)
1. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> NIL
1. Trace: (IS-PRIME '4)
1. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> NIL
1. Trace: (IS-PRIME '4115)
1. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> NIL
1. Trace: (IS-PRIME '5)
1. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
1. Trace: (IS-PRIME '823)
1. Trace: IS-PRIME ==> T
(3 5 823)
```

You are checking the primality of the same numbers several times!

### Extra optimization

`primep` can find a divisor, not just check primality.

### Optimized algorithm

```
(defun compositep (n &optional (d (isqrt n)))
  "If n is composite, return a divisor.
Assumes n is not divisible by anything over d."
  (and (> n 1)
       (> d 1)
       (if (zerop (rem n d))
           d
           (compositep n (- d 1)))))

(defun prime-decomposition (n)
  "Return the prime decomposition of n."
  (let ((f (compositep n)))
    (if f
        (nconc (prime-decomposition (/ n f))
               (prime-decomposition f))
        (list n))))
```

Note that one final optimization is possible -
[memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) of
`compositep`:

```
(let ((known-composites (make-hash-table)))
  (defun compositep (n &optional (d (isqrt n)))
    "If n is composite, return a divisor.
Assumes n is not divisible by anything over d."
    (multiple-value-bind (value found-p) (gethash n known-composites)
      (if found-p
          value
          (setf (gethash n known-composites)
                (and (> n 1)
                     (> d 1)
                     (if (zerop (rem n d))
                         d
                         (compositep n (- d 1)))))))))
```

or, better yet, of `prime-decomposition`:

```
(let ((known-decompositions (make-hash-table)))
  (defun prime-decomposition (n)
    "Return the prime decomposition of n."
    (or (gethash n known-decompositions)
        (setf (gethash n known-decompositions)
              (let ((f (compositep n)))
                (if f
                    (append (prime-decomposition (/ n f))
                            (prime-decomposition f))
                    (list n)))))))
```

note the use or [`append` instead of
`nconc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nconc.htm).

Another interesting optimization is changing the iteration in
`compositep` from descending to ascending.
This should speedup it up considerably as it would terminate early more
often:

```
(let ((known-composites (make-hash-table)))
  (defun compositep (n)
    "If n is composite, return a divisor.
Assumes n is not divisible by anything over d."
    (multiple-value-bind (value found-p) (gethash n known-composites)
      (if found-p
          value
          (setf (gethash n known-composites)
                (loop for d from 2 to (isqrt n)
                  when (zerop (rem n d))
                  return d))))))
```

PS. This is identical to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49369108/850781

Answer (score 2):

Your `is-prime` is very suboptimal in few aspects.

I. There is no sense to check for prime factors of a number ABOVE the integral part of that number's square root.

II. Aside from 2, all other prime factors of a number are odd (if any), so you only need to check at most sqrt(n)/2 numbers.

III. And your recursion does not look tail-optimizable, so you'll need to either reshape it so that you get a single tail-call (if your CL implementation is aware of tail optimizations), or transform it into an iterative construct (which, I believe, are highly available in CL, much more than in Scheme).

After all, you don't need to obtain a list of ALL prime factors of a number to say it's composite; and even less do you need to keep a stack frame per EACH number less that it.

`prime-factors-helper` is less sensitive (all the recursive calls are either in a tail context, or in a tail modulo cons-one), but still you  don't need to check every number less than x (remember, only up to sqrt(x) and only half of them).

Additionally, concerning `(= expr 0)`, doesn't CL standard library feature a primitive predicate to compare against zero, like `zero?` in Scheme?

Comment: Yes, `zerop` as sds suggests.